# Android - Moving to a view when leaving AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, scrolltop, android-scrollview

I have a circumstance where I want to alert the user to a problem, then when they hit Ok on the dialog it should move to the view and put it at the top them to the field in question. Just can't seem to make it work. Here is the code:

```
             private ScrollView mFormScrollView;
             ...

             mFormScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.formScrollView);
             ...

             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FormActivity.this);
             builder.setTitle("Form Submit Error");
             builder.setMessage("Fix media");
             builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                        
                       final View field = mFormFields.get(missingField.getFieldKey());
                        if(field != null) {
                            mFormScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run(){
                                mFormScrollView.scrollTo(0, field.getTop());
                                } 
                            }, 30);
                        }
                }
            });
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should use "builder.show();" in your code.

Comment: Sorry - I do but it happens later. But that is not the problem - the alert works fine, only when it closes the focus is not brought to the selected view like it should (and does in another instance of my application).